# Set all values in one column to NaN if the corresponding values in another column are also NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updating

The goal is to maintain the relationship between two columns by setting to NaN all the values from one column in another column.

Having the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 4],'b': [11, 12 , 13, 14]})

     a   b
0  NaN  11
1    2  12
2  NaN  13
3    4  14
```

Maintaining the relationship from column `a` to column `b`, where all NaN values are updated results in:

```
     a    b
0  NaN  NaN
1    2   12
2  NaN  NaN
3    4   14
```

One way that it is possible to achieve the desired behaviour is:

```
df.b.where(~df.a.isnull(), np.nan)
```

Is there any other way to maintain such a relationship?

Comment: `Is there any other way...`. What's *wrong* with your current method? Are you looking for cleaner syntax, a more efficient solution, or something else?

Comment: Cleaner or recommended way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `mask` on `NaN` rows.

```
In [366]: df.mask(df.a.isnull())
Out[366]:
     a     b
0  NaN   NaN
1  2.0  12.0
2  NaN   NaN
3  4.0  14.0
```

For, presence of any `NaN` across columns use  `df.mask(df.isnull().any(1))`

Comment: You can also use `inplace=True` for the changes to stick.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) to avoid having to take the negative of your Boolean series:

```
df.b.where(df.a.notnull(), np.nan)
```

But, really, there's nothing wrong with your existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another one would be:

```
df.loc[df.a.isnull(), 'b'] = df.a
```

Isn't shorter but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dropna` with `reindex`

```
df.dropna().reindex(df.index)
Out[151]: 
     a     b
0  NaN   NaN
1  2.0  12.0
2  NaN   NaN
3  4.0  14.0
```

Comment: This solution would only work across the columns, right? I would like to be able to apply it to a single column or a selected set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where()`,

```
df['b'] = np.where(df.a.isnull(), df.a, df.b)
```

Working - np.where(condition, [a, b])

Return elements, either from `a` or `b`, depending on `condition`.

Output:

```
>>> df
    a       b
0   NaN     NaN
1   2.0     12.0
2   NaN     NaN
3   4.0     14.0
```